# How do you format multiple strings (%s) using MySQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to have multiple %s's formatted for SQL-safe inserts using the MySQLdb library using this code:

```
v = ['profileIconId', 'summonerLevel', 'revisionDate', 'id', 'name']
v += summonerId.values()
vs = ','.join(['%s'] * len(v))

con = connect(MYSQL['HOST'], MYSQL['USER'], MYSQL['PASSWORD'], MYSQL['DB'])

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    q = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO '
    q += 'summoners(%s) '
    q += 'VALUES(%s)'
    print vs,v
    cur.execute(q % vs, v )
```

I am receiving this output:

%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s ['profileIconId', 'summonerLevel', 'revisionDate', 'id', 'name', 627, 30, 1398707724000, 60783, u'TheOddOne']

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

How would I get SQL-safe escaped strings using the two %s? I'm open for better ways to do this as well.

Comment: Paramterized queries cannot substitute in metadata.

Comment: What would the best way to accomplish escaping two lists into a MySQLdb execute command efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to dynamically insert column names, appropriate solution for you - combining parameterized queries with `MySQLdb.escape_string`:

```
q = "INSERT IGNORE INTO summoners({0},{1},{2},{3},{4}) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)".format(*c)
query =  MySQLdb.escape_string(q)
cursor.execute(query, v)
```